# Sharpdevelop - set the default project for solution

Tags: setup-project, sharpdevelop

Maybe this is a stupid question, but here I go :)

I have two projects in one solution. WinApp and ConsoleApp. If i have open only files from ConsoleApp then sharpdevelop launches the WinApp. I have to right-click ConsoleApp and choose "Run project".

How can I tell sharpdevelop which one of the two to run, by default, when I pressed F5?

I'm using sharpdevelop 4.2.2 build 8818

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Projects window, right click the ConsoleApp project and select **Set as Startup Project**. SharpDevelop will then run the ConsoleApp when you press F5.

Comment: Great that worked! i was looking for something like that, but apparently in the wrong place :)